# Zend Framework. Add elements in form in a single row

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on Zend Framework 1.2

I have a problem. i would  create a form in the same line but with my actual code:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'prod_name', array(
'required'   => true,
'multioptions'=> $portales,
           'label'      => 'Portales Suscritos:',
'style' => 'display: inline;'
       ));

$this->addElement('submit', 'submit1', array(
           'ignore'   => true,
           'label'    => 'Cambiar',
'style' => 'display: inline;'
       ));
```

it display  in two rows. One row with label "Portales Suscritos:" and the selector and then a second row with one space and the button submit

[image: example]

I would like that it display in a single row

Any idea?? thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to display the form like your format use **Form Decorators** .And also you can create own custom decorators which you want to display the form.You didn't use any **table or div** format. so that you can display the form whatever you like.

Here i am giving example for custom decorators.

```
$_FormElementDecorators =  array(

                   'ViewHelper',

                   'Description',

                   'Errors',

                   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td','style'=>'class_name')),

                   array('Label', array('tag' => 'td', 'class'=>'labelcolor'))


           );
```

For more information regarding Zend Form Decorators check this link http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.form.decorators.html

Thanks